# TFS tf branch command error: no appropriate mapping exists for

Tags: tfs

I'm trying to use `tf branch`, but get this error:

> no appropriate mapping exists for **$/main_folder/folderB/folder1**

below is my command:

```
tf branch $/main_folder/folderA/folder1/file.sql $/main_folder/folderB/folder1
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: You need to map to your workspace also the second branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **branch** command copies an item or set of items, including metadata and version control history, from one location to another in the Team Foundation version control server and in the local workspace.

According to above error info, you also **need to map** your `$/main_folder/folderB/folder1` path to your local workspace. Then try to perform the command again.

More detail tutorial about how to use this command please refer this official tutorial:  *[Branch Command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/branch-command?view=vsts)*

---

A sample full command in cmd with using tf.exe branch command for your reference:

```
tf branch $/ScrumProject/TestCaseProject  $/ScrumProject/Test  /w:WPATRICK-W10
```

[image]